# Getting exception org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/camel/CamelContext

Tags: java, jax-ws, apache-camel

I am sending the email using Apache Camel. When I call the send method from my main class I am not getting any exception but when I am trying to invoke it from rest services then I am getting this exception, the full trace is here:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/i-am-getting-exception-org-apache-cxf-interceptor-Fault-org-apache-camel-CamelContext-td5742012.html#a5742016

This is my method of rest services.

```
    @POST
@Path("/sendemail")
public Response sendEmail(final String userdata)
{
    System.out.println("the starting of the send email process");
    ResponseBuilder builder=Response.ok();
    JSONObject data=(JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(userdata);

    EmailInterface ei=new EmailInterface();
    boolean status=ei.sendEmail(data);
    if(status)
        builder.status(200).entity("SUCCESS");
    else
        builder.status(400).entity("UN SUCCESS");
    return builder.build();
}
```

This method invokes the method of the EmailInterface class.

```
 public class EmailInterface {
   private CamelContext camel;
   private ProducerTemplate template;

public boolean sendEmail(JSONObject data)
{
    boolean status=false;
    camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
    template = camel.createProducerTemplate();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("To",data.getString("toaddress"));
    String body = data.getString("body");
    map.put("Subject", data.getString("subject"));
    map.put("From", "xxxx@yahoo.com");

    template.sendBodyAndHeaders("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?                 username=xxxxx@gmail.com&password=ixxxxx", body, map);
    status=true;
    return status;

}
  public static void main(String args[])
{

    JSONObject data=new JSONObject();
    data.put("toaddress", "xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
    data.put("subject", "Service Status");
    data.put("body", "hi testing message");
    EmailInterface emailInterface=new EmailInterface();
    System.out.println(emailInterface.sendEmail(data));
}
```

When I call from the main method of EmailInterface, then its working fine and sends the  email, but when I try to call from rest then I am only getting this execption.

Comment: It seems that you have a problem with your libs (*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/CamelContext*). Are you sure that camel libs are included in your war when you deploy your web service ?

Comment: i included two lib file into class path.so its working from main class but not working from rest uri.

Comment: hey.i included in class path then its not working but when i pute in apache lib folder then its working fine...thanks you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem with your libs `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/CamelContext`.

Include them in the server's lib folder.